# Proper way to segue between two simple View Controllers in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7

I'm mainly from a C# background, so the workflow for iOS is a bit unusual for me, at least for now.

I was having a problem having simple segue from a main menu, to a another menu/work area, and then with the ability to go back to the main menu.

For a test, apparently I did something wrong.

I didn't write any code for this test to exhibit the problem.

What I did was just,

- create a new single-view app
- drag an additional view controller onto the work area
- drag the start arrow to the new view controller (so it becomes the initial view, same thing as checking the checkbox to set it as the initial view)
- added a button to each view controller
- Ctrl + clicked and dragged the buttons to the opposing view
- for the segue type, I chose "replace"
- now the program crashes if I hit the second button to go back to the "main menu" (green view controller in this example)

So what am I doing wrong?  Do I need to add some form of delegate or something?

I did find this, though it present fewer segue options in the tutorial than what I have.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html

These are the options I have when I Ctrl + Click from a button to another view
-Push
-Modal
-PopOver
-Custom
-Replace

Comment: Yes, I just created another test, did the same steps, and still get more options than than in the tutorial.  Once I get more than 10 rep points, I can post an image of it. :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the iPad tag -- you only get those extra choices with an iPad. A replace segue can only be used with a split view controller. Did you not get a "Could not find a split view controller ancestor ..." error message? So what exactly is your question. If you want to go from one controller to another (with just 2 UIViewControllers), use a modal segue. However, you wouldn't use a segue to go back to the initial controller, unless you use an unwind segue.

Comment: Have you embedded a navigation controller? You need to go to editor->embed in-> Navigation Controller.                                    You need a navigation controller for push segue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Have you embedded a navigation controller? You need to go to editor->embed in-> Navigation Controller. You need a navigation controller for push segue. –  Kaushal Bisht"

**This solved it for me.**  Now I'm just going to work on replacing the navigation bar with custom UI controls.

Thanks everyone! :)